# Parse XML file to add multiple marker on Android Google Map Application

Tags: android, api, xml-parsing, google-maps-markers

I have a problem in using XML parse for add multiple marker in android map application

this my XML file

```
<PA>
<node>
    <id>1</id>
    <nama>SMP 8  Cimahi</nama>
    <longitude>-6.905424</longitude>
    <latitude>107.527678</latitude>
    <kategori>sekolah</kategori>
</node>
<node>
    <id>2</id>
    <nama>SMA 4  Cimahi</nama>
    <longitude>-6.903954</longitude>
    <latitude>107.521816</latitude>
    <kategori>sekolah</kategori>
</node>
```

this my code in Java

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.petacimahi);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint(-6894581,107536519));
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    TextView id[];
    TextView nama[];
    TextView longitude[];
    TextView latitude[];
    TextView kategori[];

    try {

         DocumentBuilderFactory DBF;
            DocumentBuilder DB;
            Document dom;
            Element elt;

            DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = DB.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("database.xml")));
            elt = dom.getDocumentElement(); 

        NodeList nodeList = elt.getElementsByTagName("node");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        id = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        nama = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        longitude = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        latitude = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }


}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

How can i parse the location (langitude, latitude) to add multiple marker in Android google map application ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk/ showing several different PNGs on a single ItemizedOverlay. You just have to override some of the drawing methods to handle the different PNGs.

Comment: your answer not use XML parse